# Editable DIV HTML CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

I need a div that should be
 1. Resizeable and
 2. Editable.

And should work in IE and Chrome.

So if I start to edit in the div and if i reach the end of the line in that div then the cursor should move to next line. How do i achieve it.

Below is the code i tried but it does work in IE but not properly.
However it is not working in chrome. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
$("#resizable").resizable();
```

```css
#resizable {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body contenteditable="false">


  <div id="resizable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, chrome is adding the content you're typing into the box to the right drag handle.  You can use the `create` callback to disable content editing on the drag handles to get it to work in chrome.

```js
$("#resizable").resizable({
  create: function( event, ui ) {
    this.childNodes.forEach(function(child){
      child.contentEditable = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#resizable {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body contenteditable="false">


  <div id="resizable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a div element?  This is what textarea elements are for.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
This is editable.
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is editable but not able to resizeable in IE . But resizeable in chrome

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a bug, when the div is empty the typed text is writed in the first "child" that's the right draggable bar.

As you can see in the DOM (at 2nd line):

```
<div id="resizable" contenteditable="true" class="ui-resizable" style="height: 121px; width: 197px;">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;">THE TYPED TEXT GOES HERE!</div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

Anyway, you could simply put an empty char (`&nbsp;`) into the div and it works. See following snippet please:

```js
$( ".resizable" ).resizable();
```

```css
.resizable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.grid {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  Editable div:
  <div class="resizable" contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  Not editable div:
  <div class="resizable" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alessandrop thanks for the solution . However it is not working in IE propoerly.

Comment: Hi Alessandro thanks for the solution . However, it is not working in IE properly. That means consider am in 2nd line and typing some texts without  **any space**  the letters goes beyond div element width. and  also the div not align itself to resize or not providing a scroller  in a  scenario where am in the **last line** of the div and want to add more lines beyond the size of the DIV element.These two issue are still there.